# Can lapply pass (to a function) values stored in a vector, successively

Tags: r, lapply

I need lapply to pass (to a function) values stored in a vector, successively.

```
values <- c(10,11,13,10)
lapply(foo,function(x) peakabif(x,npeaks=values))
```

So to get :

```
peakabif(x1,npeaks=10)
peakabif(x2,npeaks=11)
peakabif(x3,npeaks=13)
peakabif(x4,npeaks=10)
```

Is this possible or do I need to reconsider using lapply ?
Is a for loop inside the function would work ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use `mapply` for this: `mapply(peakabif, x=foo, npeaks=values)`

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of ways to handle this.  You could try a straight indexing vector approach.

```
lapply(1:length(foo), function(i) peakabif(foo[i], npeaks=values[i]))
```

(and someone already beat me to the mapply version...)

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you can convert an existing function so that it will accept vectors (or lists)  using `Vectorize`

```
vrep <- Vectorize(rep.int)
> vrep(list(1:4, 1:5), list(2,3) )
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4

[[2]]
 [1] 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5
```

(Under the hood it's really a convenience wrapper for `mapply` in the same way the `read.table` is a wrapper for `scan`.)