# Pass interable items to function parameters in R

Tags: r

I have a function that takes two arguments, a link and and an State name abbreviation. The function gets a spreadsheet from a remote site and 
makes me a data frame of the state data that I want.

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)
library(gdata)
library(dplyr)
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

nsw_link <-  'http://www.abs.gov.au/ausstats/abs@archive.nsf/log?openagent&3101051.xls&3101.0&Time%20Series%20Spreadsheet&3F92BFA30BC29940CA257F1D001427C3&0&Jun%202015&17.12.2015&Latest'
qld_link <- "http://www.abs.gov.au/ausstats/abs@archive.nsf/log?openagent&3101053-.xls&3101.0&Time%20Series%20Spreadsheet&2927EBD7E6856BABCA257F1D0014283D&0&Jun%202015&17.12.2015&Latest"
vic_link <- "http://www.abs.gov.au/ausstats/abs@archive.nsf/log?openagent&3101052.xls&3101.0&Time%20Series%20Spreadsheet&E3B2958632AB29ECCA257F1D001427FB&0&Jun%202015&17.12.2015&Latest"
nt_link <- "http://www.abs.gov.au/ausstats/abs@archive.nsf/log?openagent&3101057.xls&3101.0&Time%20Series%20Spreadsheet&CCB60AB638D60938CA257F1D0014291C&0&Jun%202015&17.12.2015&Latest"
tas_link <- "http://www.abs.gov.au/ausstats/abs@archive.nsf/log?openagent&3101056.xls&3101.0&Time%20Series%20Spreadsheet&8CA5625A306A4805CA257F1D001428D7&0&Jun%202015&17.12.2015&Latest"
act_link <- "http://www.abs.gov.au/ausstats/abs@archive.nsf/log?openagent&3101058.xls&3101.0&Time%20Series%20Spreadsheet&4234206BA89A82F6CA257F1D00142959&0&Jun%202015&17.12.2015&Latest"
sa_link <- "http://www.abs.gov.au/ausstats/abs@archive.nsf/log?openagent&3101054.xls&3101.0&Time%20Series%20Spreadsheet&A342BFFB06A62F4FCA257F1D0014286D&0&Jun%202015&17.12.2015&Latest"
wa_link <- "http://www.abs.gov.au/ausstats/abs@archive.nsf/log?openagent&3101055.xls&3101.0&Time%20Series%20Spreadsheet&DC6208699BE4D2FFCA257F1D0014289E&0&Jun%202015&17.12.2015&Latest"

get_ERP_data <- function(link, state){

    # Get the xls file and slice only the columns needed for male and female ERPs
    xls_data <- read.xls(link, sheet = 'Data1')
    xls_data <- tbl_df(xls_data)
    xls_data <- xls_data[, 1:203]

    names(xls_data) <- gsub(pattern = "Estimated.Resident.Population....", '',  names(xls_data))
    names(xls_data) <- gsub('[.]+', '', names(xls_data))
    names(xls_data) <- gsub('100andover', '101', names(xls_data))
    names(xls_data) <- gsub("(\\d+)$", ".\\1", names(xls_data))


    xls_data <- xls_data[28:54, ]
    names(xls_data)[1] <- 'Year'


    xls_data$Year <- paste('01', xls_data$Year, sep = '-')
    xls_data$Year <- dmy(xls_data$Year)
    xls_data$Year <- year(xls_data$Year)


    # make a long version of the ERP data
    xls_data_long <- xls_data %>% gather(Sex_Age, Population, Male.0:Female.101)

    # Make two new column, sex and age, from the sex_age column
    xls_data_sep_log <- xls_data_long %>% separate(Sex_Age, c('Sex', 'Age'))

    # Recode observations from 101 to 'over 100'
    xls_data_sep_log$Age[grep(xls_data_sep_log$Age, pattern = '101')] <- 'Over 100'
    xls_data_sep_log$State <- state


    df_name <- paste(state, 'data', sep = '_')

    assign(df_name,xls_data_sep_log,envir = .GlobalEnv)


}


link_list <- list(act_link, nsw_link, nt_link, qld_link, sa_link, tas_link, vic_link, wa_link)
states <- c('ACT', 'NSW', 'NT', 'QLD', 'SA', 'TAS', 'VIC', 'WA')
```

For example, if I want Queensland estimated resident population data I run:

```
get_ERP_data(qld_link, 'QLD')
```

This makes me a longitudinal data frame of the data I need.

I would like to extend this so that I can pass a vector or list of states to a list of links as parameter and return a data frame for each 
argument in the paramter? I am not particularly concerned with binding resulting data frames in the function output.

Similar to the example above, how could I get my function to run something like:

```
get_ERP_data(as.list(qld_link, nsw_link), c('QLD', 'NSW'))
```

I tried using variations of sapply and do.call but did not get very far. Is there a way to use some equivalent of pythons *args/**kwargs 
to pass lists as arguments to my function?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what was wrong with the `sapply`/`do.call` approaches you used, exactly?

Comment: When I ran 'sapply(link_list, get_ERP_data, state = states)' it worked for the first one then gave me this error:    ' Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "State", value = c("ACT", "NSW", "NT",  : 
  replacement has 8 rows, data has 5454 '

Comment: `Vectorize(get_ERP_data)(qld_link, c('QLD', 'NSW'))` might be the easiest way

Comment: You need to use the multi-parameter version of `sapply`, `mapply`. Better yet, `Map` — it doesn’t auto-coerce the result into a magical type.

Comment: @rawr that is exacly what I wanted! Wow. Please can you add it as an answer.

Comment: maybe [this q/a](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265720/can-lapply-pass-to-a-function-values-stored-in-a-vector-successively) is more useful. it demonstrates the `s/lapply` method you tried and the `mapply` that konrad mentioned