# Iterating over the argument of a function (grep) passed to lapply

Tags: r, lapply

I currently am doing an operation similar to below:

```
v<-c("my","pig","is","big","with","a","name")
s<-c("m","g")
for(i in c(1:length(s))){
    print(grep(v,pattern=s[i]))
}
```

Which prints

```
[1] 1 7
[1] 2 4
```

I would like to instead vectorize this operation where the return values are stored in a vector. I tried

```
 mynewvector<-lapply(v,grep,pattern=s,x=v)
```

but the problem is that I don't know how to get `lapply` iterate over the elements passed as arguments (e.g. iterating over s).  I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265720/can-lapply-pass-to-a-function-values-stored-in-a-vector-successively) answer, but I don't think `mapply` works here because I am trying to hold one argument constant (`x=v`) and iterate over the other argument (`pattern=s`)

How would I do this?

Comment: ?`lapply(s, grep, x = v)`

Comment: Consider also using `stringr::str_detect` which is vectorized over both arguments: `outer(v,s,stringr::str_detect)` will give you a `length(v)`x`lenght(s)` matrix whose `i,j` element indicates whether the `i`th element of `v` contained the `j`th pattern of `s`.

Comment: @Richard Telford. How does `lapply(X, FUN, ...)` know which argument `X` should be passed as to `FUN()`?

Comment: it uses the first available one

Comment: @irritable_phd_syndrom, Richard's function is shorthand for `lapply(s, function(a) grep(pattern = a, x = v))` which, hopefully is more readable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on d.b.'s response, the most clear solution is

```
lapply(s, function(a) grep(pattern = a, x = v))
```